# How to disiable navigation bar in openbravo 3

Tags: openbravo

I would like to disable top navigation bar for certain users.

- Quick Menus
- Create New
- Launch
- Application Menu
- Alerts
- Log out
- User Preferences
- Help.

I would like to show only workspace with default widgets in it when certain users logs into openbravo.

How to achieve the above features in openbravo.

Any help greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to hide tool bar [here](http://forums.openbravo.com/viewtopic.php?f=549512&t=7033397&p=7038668&sid=f851ab03d2c90611bd4dbafdf92a97d0#p7038668) via preferences. But Openbravo core customization is required to disiable top navigation bar in openbravo 3. It is not possible to achieve the above using openbravo's extended module feature. Check this [link](http://forums.openbravo.com/viewtopic.php?f=549512&t=7033413&sid=ff7c722e98aeefebb4183dc8a5b6edf1)

Answer (score 1):

1) You can enable portal interface

(from http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Role)
For Portal Users: If checked, this role will have a simplified (portal) interface, where we may see only configured workspace widgets with role access. **Portal interface changes the look and feel of the workspace**. Top page menu and left-side menu are hidden. Usually a role for Portal Users givess access to users only to their own information using widgets.

2) To remove logout link you have to add patch/tweak client application module

3) Since portal interface also disables left-side menu (i.e recent views, recent documents etc) to enable you have to add patch/tweak client application module

patches or changes may need to go on smartclient code as well as java code related to default workspace